# How run network process in background after closing View?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, image, background-process

I'm working on a chat application. If i open a chat and start downloading an Image which is `onClick()` method of that chat view controller, how do i keep continue downloading that image in background even after View is closed (popped back). I've seen this in WhatsApp. I'm using Alamofire currently to download image.

Comment: Heard of Background sessions of NSURLSession introduced in iOS 8 ?? It was designed and intended for downloading content in background infact to download the content even if the app is killed in between :)

Answer (score 1):

At first, You should have to see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

What if your general-purpose task could be finished in less than 3 minutes, use `[UIApplication beginBackgroundTaskWithName]`.

Otherwise, what if the task is related with network, use `NSURLSession`.

Details are described in [the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html).

Answer (score 1):

In order download the content when the app is background or to continue downloading even if user kills the app in between, you should consider making use of Background session configuration of NSURLSession.

```
let backgroundSession = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "abcd")
let session = URLSession(configuration: backgroundSession)


let url = URL(string: "abcd")
session.downloadTask(with: url!, completionHandler: { (url,response,error) in

}).resume()
```

- Make sure you make use of unique identifier,
- Prefer using NSURLsession delegates than completion blocks which is also called as custom delegates in docs, I din wanted to write ready made code hence kept the completion block
- If your app needs to handle some kind of authentications then handle `didRecieveChallenge` and other delegates as well :)
- If your app needs to deal with session expiration scenario handle the delegates handle `application:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:`and `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession:` as well :)

Happy coding :)